# passing data to another page angular js

Tags: angularjs, service

I am new to Angular js and want to pass the data from a submit to another page.

How can I make this in angularjs?

I can add lists to a single customer, but I can display the data only in the same page. 
I want to display the data in another page after the submit.
I have learnd today, how to use the services, but still I can not pass data from a page to another. 
Can anyone help me with a example? 
Sorry for my bad English and thank you

```
        // ngRoute code
    var app = angular.module('appCheck', ['ngRoute', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        controller  : "customersCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/customers/customers.html"
    })

    .when("/customers", {
        controller  : "customersCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/customers/customers.html"
    })
    .when("/lists", {
        controller  : "listsCTRL",
        templateUrl : "/app/lists/lists.html"
    })

    .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
    });


   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

}]);


// controller code

 $scope.getList = function(id)  {

  listsService.getSingleCustomer(id)
  .then(function successCallback(response, data) {

     //$scope.clearForm();
     $scope.customer = response.data[0].name;  
     $scope.id_customer = response.data[0].id;  
     //$scope.getAll();

     //console.log(id);
  })
}

$scope.createList = function createList() {


 listsService.createList() 

 .then(function successCallback(response, data) {


    $('#addLists').modal('hide');
    $scope.clearForm();

 })  

};



// services code
this.createLists = function() {
       return $http.post('/lists/add' , {

              "name" : $scope.name,
              "id_customer" : $scope.id_customer
           })
    }


<button ng-click="getListExample(x.id)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addL"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"> Add List</span></button>

    <h4 class="modal-title">Add Liste for the customer <span contenteditable="false" ng-bind="cust"></span></h4>

    <label>Name of the List</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">

    <button type="button" ng-click="createListExample()" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
```

Comment: can u share the html code.also share controller code.

Comment: @dani, you want to send a value or whole data.

Comment: @vinoth I want to send the ID of the customer. Example: after submit I want another page with the adress customers/getonecustomer/12. In this page must show the customer with id 12 and all the lists to the single customer

Comment: @balasubramanian you can find the controller and the service, html code above.

Comment: @dani you can save all the customer id by using session. and then you can use where it is required.

Comment: I have treid, but no success. Can I save all the customer with a service, like my code? Can I retrieve a single customer in Angular JS? I have yet a json data, with the single customer

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass data. Instead, the other page should get the data it needs to show, from the backend, based on the path parameters.

So the path for the list of customers should be `/customers`. The associated component gets the list of customers from the backend.

Then, to display a single customer, you would go to `/customers/:customerId` (example: /customers/42). The componenty would get the details of the customer 42 from the backend.

To display the lists of the customer 42, for example after you have added a list to that customer, you would go to `/customers/:customerId/lists` (example: /customers/42/lists). The component would get the lists of the customer 42 from the backend.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have in the backend /customers/getallcustomers and /customers/getonecustomer. I have the /lists/getlists for the lists. I can get at the moment a single customer and all the lists of the single customer, but in the same page. I want to show the single customer with all the lists in one separate page. Example: customers/getonecustomer/31 and this adress must show to me a single customer with all the lists

Comment: My answer still applies. On the page /customers/:customerId, get the customer and its lists from the backend, thanks to the ID of the customer in the path parameter. This soesn't need to pass data to another page. Only to navigate to that page.

Comment: Thank you, but can I make this only with Angular Js? For example to show a single customer per ID? I have a json and I want this to make in Angular JS

Comment: Yes, this question is about AngularJS, and my answer is about AngularJS.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Angular js, but I have yet the backend with nodejs, express and mysql. Can you post a code example? Please and thanks for all answers

Comment: No. This is not about code. This is about understanding the principle of routing. What don't you understand? This has **nothing** to do with the backend.

Comment: I have treid to make /customers/:id in route, but I cant receive the data for the single customer. I have a route with /customers/:id, then a new template, singlecustomer.html. I want to understand, how can I get the data to the singlecustomer.html. In customers.html I can get all the customer, and with a button, all the lists that a single customer have, but this is all in one page. I read the route documentation, but I dont undertand who is the problem

Comment: You should have a backend service that allows getting one customer, by its ID. If you don't, and can't add one, then get them all again and filter the result to find the one with the given ID.

Comment: No. I mean your server. Your server should expose a REST service that allows getting one customer, by its ID. If it doesn't, and you and can't add one, then get them all again using the service that returns all customers, and filter the result to find the one with the given ID

Comment: I have a REST service that allows to get one customer. I can get all customers, one single customer, all lists, one single list. In json format. I can see the lists for the single customer, but in the same page who I have all the customers. I have a button, example: CustomerDani (click here) and I can have all the lists for CustomerDani. I want to have CustomerDani in a separate page, that show ONLY CustomerDani + the lists of CustomerDani

Comment: So, read my answer again. It explains how to do. What don't you understand?

Comment: my problem was at the json array. I didn't get anything in html, except with ng-repeat. So with {{customer.name[0]}} in html I can get the data for the single customer. Thanks